# XPression Events not fired

Tags: c#, events, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to add listeners to a scene in a Ross XPression project. I am using the sequencer in XPression Developer. When I press the '+' button on my keyboard while selecting a scene in the sequencer I expect something to be written to the console.
Here's the output from console:

```
scene.Name == Opener
scene.AnimControllerCount == 2
animController.Name == AnimController1
animController.Name == Rotate
```

And here is my code:

```
private xpEngine engine;
private xpProject project;
private xpScene scene;
private xpAnimController animController1;
private xpAnimController animController2;

public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        engine = new xpEngine();
        project = engine.ActiveProject;
        if (project.GetSceneByName("Opener",out scene))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("scene.Name == " + scene.Name);
            scene.OnSceneState += Scene_OnSceneState;
            scene.SceneDirector.OnSceneDirectorState += SceneDirector_OnSceneDirectorState;

            Console.WriteLine("scene.AnimControllerCount == " + scene.AnimControllerCount);
            if (scene.GetAnimController(0, out animController1))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("animController.Name == " + animController1.Name);
                animController1.OnStateChange += AnimController_OnStateChange;
            }
            if (scene.GetAnimController(1, out animController2))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("animController.Name == " + animController2.Name);
                animController2.OnStateChange += AnimController_OnStateChange;
            }
        }

    }

private void SceneDirector_OnSceneDirectorState(xpSceneDirector Director, SceneDirectorState State)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Director: " + Director.Name + " State: " + State);
    }

    private void Scene_OnSceneState(xpScene Scene, int State)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Scene: " + Scene.Name + " State: " + State);
    }

    private void AnimController_OnStateChange(xpAnimController Controller, PlayState State)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Controller: " + Controller.Name + " State: " + State);
    }
```

The sequencer itself makes a copy of the scene, so I can't figure a way to do this. As you can see from the output, the events are not fired. Why is that? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using a older version of the XPression API (v6.0). After updating to version 6.1 I was able to use the new xpOutputFrameBuffer Object : OnSceneState Event. I am now able to listen for scene states in the output:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using XPression;

namespace mynamespace
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private xpEngine engine;
        private xpOutputFrameBuffer outputFrameBuffer;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            engine = new xpEngine();
            if (engine.GetOutputFrameBuffer(0, out outputFrameBuffer))
            {
                outputFrameBuffer.OnSceneState += OutputFrameBuffer_OnSceneState;
            }
        }

        private void OutputFrameBuffer_OnSceneState(xpScene Scene, int State)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Scene: " + Scene.Name + " State: " + State);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Scene: Opener State: 0
Scene: Opener State: 1
```